# Need suggestion formore pretty sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, it does what it is supposed to do.
It finds all records in table 1that have a match in table 2, and assign a pseudo column value 1.
Then it union a query that retreive all records in table 1 that does not have a match in table 2, and assign a pseudo column value 0.
This works, but I am sure it is possible to do it in a more effective way.

```sql
SELECT aplac.*, 1 AS selected
FROM aux_placements aplac
JOIN product_placements pplac
ON pplac.placement_id = aplac.placement_id
WHERE pplac.product_id = 1
UNION
SELECT distinct aplac.*, 0 AS selected
FROM aux_placements aplac
WHERE placement_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT aplac.placement_id
    FROM aux_placements aplac
    JOIN product_placements pplac
    ON pplac.placement_id = aplac.placement_id
    WHERE pplac.product_id = 1)
```

I was thinking something like this might work:

```sql
SELECT aplac.*,
       CASE WHEN aplac.placement_id IS NULL 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 
       END AS selected
FROM aux_placements aplac 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_placements pplac
ON pplac.placement_id = aplac.placement_id
WHERE pplac.product_id = 1;
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: sqlfiddle is avaliable here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57013a/1

Comment: In your second query, change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want the product id selection to be part of the join condition - change `WHERE` to `AND`.
2. You want to check whether the join found a matching record in the second table - change `aplac.placement_id` to `pplac.placement_id`.

So the next query will work for you:

```
SELECT aplac.*,
       CASE WHEN pplac.placement_id IS NULL 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 
       END AS selected
FROM aux_placements aplac 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_placements pplac
ON pplac.placement_id = aplac.placement_id
AND pplac.product_id = 1;
```